# Invalid conversion from runtime type Decimal to Integer

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am getting an invalid conversion error when trying to access an element from an array but don't understand why..

## Class

```
public with sharing class WspController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static WSP_Politic__c saveWSP (Integer[] answers)
        System.debug('answers--->'+answers[1]); //Error
    }
}
```

## Controller

```
score: function(component, event, helper) {
    var answerArr = [1, 2, 1, 3, 5, 2, -1, -3, 6];
    component.set("v.answers", answerArr);
}
scoreSet: function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.saveWSP");
    action.setParams({
        "answers": component.get("v.answers")
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        console.log('State-->' + state);
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

## Component

```
  <aura:component access="global" controller="WspController">
    <aura:attribute name="answers" type="Integer[]" />
  </aura:component>
```

Comment: What have you defined the "answers" component as? I wonder if it's because you have negative numbers in your array? (I thought integers by default would be signed, but perhaps they are unsigned by default and if negative, become decimals)

Comment: I'm investigating

Comment: Updated the code..

Comment: There is no "integer" type in Javascript, just [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number), which is analogous to `double` in Apex.  I wonder if the framework doesn't allow the conversion because it would be similar to an implicit conversion from `double` to `integer`, which is illegal in Apex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I've tested.

If you change your method signature to

```
public static WSP_Politic__c saveWSP (Decimal[] answers)
```

It will fix the error (which I assumed you knew). However, I was unable to get it to change by removing negative values.

It looks like it sends all numbers as Decimals, even if you specified the `aura:component` as an Integer.

Your other option if you really really want it to be an integer is either serialize the dataload as a string and JSON decode it or typecast it inside your Apex method.

There is no real downside to it being a Decimal in Apex, however, so you may as well just change the method signature.

Comment: To be pedantic, there is a downsize to using Decimal, that being it uses 36 bytes of memory per value compared to Integer's 4. However, you're right that it doesn't matter in most trivial applications you'd use Deciml for, but it is something to be aware of if you're doing something crazy like uploading a binary file in Decimal format.

Comment: Wow that is a lot more memory. I'll keep that in mind if I ever run into heap issues

Comment: Yeah, Decimals can hold very large and very small numbers, so they should only be used in small doses, like when you need to calculate taxes accurately and stuff. Try not to keep large lists of them in memory any more than necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Decimals worked.. I did consider putting decimals but hadn't tried it as using Integer made sense to me..

Answer (score 4):

The aura framework is sending numbers as decimals at runtime but your Apex method is assuming those are integers.

It can be corrected by updating the signature and then working with the Decimal type, or you can [convert to Integer](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_decimal.htm#apex_methods_system_decimal) if that's what's necessary.

```
public with sharing class WspController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static WSP_Politic__c saveWSP (Decimal[] answers)
        System.debug('answers--->'+answers[1]); //Error
    }

    /*
    @AuraEnabled
    public static WSP_Politic__c saveWSP (Decimal[] answers)
        System.debug('answers--->' + answers[1].intValue()));
    }
    */
}
```